# Way of measuring thickness of a glass

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics

Imagine you have a laser pointer and a glass. You don't know the refractive index of the glass and you just have Wavelength of laser!
How can you measure the thickness of glass?

**(I have some idea but please tell me your ideas and then we will have discussion!)**

Comment: You need to specify the scenario/rules in more detail. Why can't you just measure the thickness of the glass? What other items do you have available? How accurately could you measure the power of reflected/transmitted light? Do you have the ability to analyse polarisation?

Comment: Too should really add your ideas first....

Comment: @RobJeffries So , this is the exact question : Invent and construct an optical device that uses a laser pointer and allows contactless determination of thickness, refractive index, and other properties of a glass sheet.
but You mustn't answer to this ,,,,,,,,, this is just an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Floris' answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/200017/1325) to [Calculating light's lateral shift in a glass slab](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/199995/calculating-lights-lateral-shift-in-a-glass-slab).

If you shine your laser through the glass plate at an angle $\theta$ then the beam will be deflected by a distance $x$ given by:

$$ x =d\sin\theta\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}{\sqrt{n^2-\sin^2\theta}}\right) $$

where $d$ is the unknown thickness of the plate and $n$ is the unknown refractive index. If you measure the displacement $x_1$ for an angle $\theta_1$ then measure the displacement $x_2$ for a different angle $\theta_2$ then you can divide the two displacements to get:

$$ \frac{x_1}{x_2} = \frac{\sin\theta_1\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta_1}}{\sqrt{n^2-\sin^2\theta_1}}\right)}{\sin\theta_2\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta_2}}{\sqrt{n^2-\sin^2\theta_2}}\right)} $$

You can solve this equation to find $n$ then substitute the value of $n$ to find $d$.

In practice you wouldn't just use two measurements. To improve accuracy you would record many values of $x$ and $\theta$ and use a curve fitting program to calculate the values of $d$ and $n$.

Comment: How to use a curve? Not any other way to solve this?

Comment: @MichaeleCastle: the problem is that the equation for $x$ is a complicated one. It's nice to be able to transform equations so that when plotted they form a straight line, but I can't think of any easy way to do this. Curve fitting can be a complicated business, but even Microsoft Excel can do basic curve fitting [using an addon called the Solver](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=excel+solver).

Comment: We have three unknown things ! $x$ , $d$ and $n$ and I don't understand what should I do for finding $d$ .... Could you explain more?

Comment: @MichaeleCastle: $x$ isn't unknown. You shine your laser through the glass and measure the angle $\theta$ and the displacement $x$.

Comment: How to measure the displacement x? We just have $\theta$ and nothing else! explain please!

Comment: @MichaeleCastle: If you just have $\theta$ you cannot measure the thickness or refractive index of the glass.

Comment: How to measure $x$ if we don't have any ruler?